# Adding UIImage to CCSprite using Box2D

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I want to add an image to a CCSprite and then use that inside my Box2d world. The `createBoxAtLocation` picks up the `contentSize` correctly but never displays the image...what am I doing wrong? Do I need to add anything to the update() function?

```
    CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"slider_piece.png"];

    [self createBoxAtLocation:loc1 withSize:boxSize forSprite:sprite];


    -(void) createBoxAtLocation:(CGPoint)location withSize:(CGSize)size forSprite:(CCSprite *)_sprite
    {   
        b2BodyDef bodyDef;
        bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
        bodyDef.position = b2Vec2(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);
        bodyDef.allowSleep = false;
        //bodyDef.userData = _sprite;

        b2Body *body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
        body->SetUserData(_sprite);

        b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;

        b2PolygonShape shape;
        shape.SetAsBox(_sprite.contentSize.width/2/PTM_RATIO, _sprite.contentSize.height/2/PTM_RATIO); 
        fixtureDef.shape = &shape;   

        body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);    
    }
```

**EDIT**

Inside the update function I have this, but it causes a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on *sprite.position* line

```
    for(b2Body *b = world->GetBodyList(); b != NULL; b = b->GetNext()) 
   {    
      if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
           CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *) b->GetUserData();
           sprite.position = ccp(b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
           sprite.rotation = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b->GetAngle() * -1);
       }       
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sprite is not addChild'ed to any CCNode(CCLayer or CCScene or so forth)?

If so,

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"slider_piece.png"];
```

the sprite might be released in update() because the sprite is autoreleased object.

You have to retain the sprite in this case at CreateBody,

```
body->SetUserData([_sprite retain]);
```

And then release it at DestroyBody.

```
[(CCSprite *)body->GetUserData() release];
```

BTW, I recommend you to use CCBox2D.

- [CCBox2D](https://github.com/axcho/CCBox2D)
- [[CCBox2D] I made a cocos2d-flavored wrapper for Box2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/15175)

**EDITED:**

Did you addChild the sprite to your CCScene or child nodes?

```
[self addChild:sprite];
```

Or the body's position (loc1) is in the screen range?

Comment: Thanks Kazuki, the retain stops the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. But the image is still not being displayed.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Also where would [(CCSprite *)body->GetUserData() release]; go?

Comment: At calling DestroyBody. However you don't need to retain/release it explicitly if you addChild the sprite to CCScene after spriteWithFile. CCScene retains/releases it properly.